# How to receive a call from GSM Modem

Tags: c#, usb, gsm, headset

I am fairly new to this area so it might look silly but I have a gsm modem connected to my pc through usb port. If somebody calls that number i need to pick it up and transfer to my headset. Is it possible? Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Yes obviously its possible  use AT Commands

http://www.owen.ru/uploads/re_pm01_list_command.pdf

try it works fine.

Comment: use Serial Communication by write "ATA" to Attend the call and convert stream of byte data from  analog to digital  .you will get what you asked..

Answer (score 0):

As @arun kumar non ascii mentioned you can answer the call using ATA .

You can also know the number of person calling you (i.e. Caller ID) by executing AT+CLCC

You can also set your modem to auto answer the call using `ATS0=<n>` , where `<n>` is the number of rings after which you modem should auto answer the call.