# Can I receive a phone call over my modem in C#

Tags: c#, audio, modem

I'm working a piece of software that in a perfect world would never lose an internet connection, and I could send an audio feed between two clients flawlessly. My problem is that this world is far from that. In the event of a failed internet connection and a dropped audio feed, my service is effectively worthless.

My question is this:

Is there a way in C# to attach to my systems modem and either make a call, or receive a call, (or preferably both,) and push/play audio to/from two points?

The approach is deprecated, but nearly a necessity in my scenario, and I couldn't find much on Google, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are sending audio over POTS lines, yes?  Or is this a data connection?

Comment: Interesting question. Absolutely certain this is possible but not sure how u would achieve this. I assume you would need to communicate through the com port and work out how 2 get the modem to talk to your app. It would likely largely depend on the modem, no?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to receive a call from GSM Modem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829453/how-to-receive-a-call-from-gsm-modem)

Comment: Most modern modems don't have the audio funcionality.

So you will need to use a interface like some used in Asterisk or Freeswitch.

Some of these interfaces have a SDK which will provide what you need.

I used one from Khomp (www.khomp.com) which have a SDK in C. I used PInvoke and did somethings like what you want.

Comment: That's right Brad; no data involved if we can avoid it. I suppose it would Maxim, but is there a modem standard that could be employed? I'll take a look at that @Sergio, appreciate the comment.

Answer (score 0):

No, modems (dial-up I assume you mean) do not have the ability to insert raw audio on a pots line (perhaps if you rewrite the driver though) but you may want to look into asterisk that has some really cool stuff you can mess with. But to the main point unless you forget the modem and use an ip-phone solution the answer is no.

Comment: After rereading your question Asterisk would be a good solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using a service like Twilio to handle voice calling. They have a .net client: http://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries